# Die roll problem

Tags: probability

**A regular die was rolled 9 times. Calculate the probability that at least one ,,6'' was drawn and ,,1'' points
appeared exactly once.**

I have a problem with combining the both conditions together, since I know that ,,at least one 6 was drawn" can be done by complementary events and ,,1 point exactly once" perhaps with Bernoulli trial (n=9,k=1), also know that omega = 6^9. Can anybody help me how to combine both conditions in one equation, that's the last step I miss or correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: $\binom{9}{1}\left(\frac16\right)^1\left(\frac56\right)^8$ is the probability that exactly one $1$ was rolled ([Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial)). Given that, what is the probability that at least one $6$ was rolled on the other $8$ dice?

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute the number of successful rolls out of $6^9$.  To have exactly one $1$ there are $9$ places for the $1$ and all the other rolls must be non-$1$, so there are only $5$ choices.  Now subtract from that the ones that also have only one $1$ but do not have a $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathrm N_k$ be the count for face $k$ among the nine rolls.

You seek $\mathsf P(\mathrm N_6{>}0, \mathrm N_1{=}1)$, and using the rule of relative complements:

$$\mathsf P(\mathrm N_6{>}0, \mathrm N_1{=}1)~=~\mathsf P(\mathrm N_1{=}1)-\mathsf P(\mathrm N_1{=}1,\mathrm N_6{=}0)$$

Now $\mathsf P(\mathrm N_1{=}1)$ is the probability for rolling exactly one `1` among the nine rolls.  That result is taken from the probability mass function for a Binomial Distribution, $\mathcal{Bin}(9,1/6)$.$$\mathsf P(\mathrm N_1{=}1)~=~{\dbinom 91}\dfrac {1\cdot 5^8}{6^9}$$

Likewise $\mathsf P(\mathrm N_1{=}1,\mathrm N_6=0)$ is the probability for obtaining one `1` among the nine rolls *and* no `6` among the remaining eight.   Solve it using conditioning. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\mathrm N_1{=}1,\mathrm N_6=0)~&=~\mathsf P(\mathrm N_1{=}1)\cdot\mathsf P(\mathrm N_6=0\mid \mathrm N_1{=}1)\\&=~\dbinom 91\dfrac {1\cdot 5^8}{6^9}\cdot\boxed{?}\end{align}$$

> $\mathsf P(\mathrm N_6=0\mid \mathrm N_1{=}1)$ is the probability for rolling no `6` among eight dice *when given* those dice do not show any `1` (but the other *five* faces each have equal bias).